# Create a custom function for neural nets classification

Tags: r

I have a general question(not dataset specific):

Say I have two columns A and B,and a Class column say C which has two class labels C1 and C2,now the way I got C1 and C2 is by using following:

```
formula = IF(A - B >0) then C1 else C2
```

Now if i try to do this:

```
library(neuralnet)

nn<-neuralnet(f,train_set,hidden = c(1),linear.output = FALSE,stepmax = 1e6)
```

Here can I modify function `f` to the above formula to classify if yes how? Because otherwise it simply assumes `C~A+B`.

Please let me know, also I am new to this field so if I have asked something entirely wrong please correct me.

Comment: What's wrong with the formula `C~A+B` ?

Comment: C~A+B does not classify anything on my test set.

Comment: please provide example data, your question is unclear.

Comment: ok so ,say A=42.6414 B=40.86509 consider these two values for A and B column,now column C will be assigned label C1 if (A-B)>0 else C2,this is how I have generated class labels,now I want to divide my entire set into test and train set and run neural net on train set and then check it on test set with respect to the above-formed class labels,so how do i do that?